# How to separate concepts within one .NET class library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, class-library, conceptual

I like how concepts can be separated when solution is split into multiple class libraries. For example:

```
System.IO.csproj,            Stream class
System.IO.Net.csproj,        NetworkStream class
System.IO.Filesystem.csproj, FileStream class
System.IO.Extensions.csproj, bunch of classes which builds on top of System.IO
```

This way I can be pretty sure that `Stream` class knows nothing about `NetworkStream`, which is the way it should be. When someone tries to create hack involving `NetworkStream` inside `Stream` class, he gets compiler error, perfect!

In similar fashion, when someone tries to add some method to `Stream`, which takes as argument something from Extensions, he gets compile error too, great! People sometimes try to create dependency which should never exist.

**Is there a way to separate concepts in similar way within one class library?** If not to enforce it, is there at least a way to test it?

From my experience, multiple class libraries works best, and it's easy to manage it's references (that's the enforcement), but it seems impractical to have large number of class libraries. I often have some **core** code, then there's bunch of **extensions**, then there's **2nd level extensions** which uses other extensions etc. In ideal world, each extension would be separated from another.

Then there's application or library which consumes the functionality and from it's point of view, it's best when everything is one class library.

Comment: You can declare a class within another class in c#.  You can also use the private modifier on a class declaration.  The class within a class plus the public private modifiers would do what you are talking about.  Also you can have different namespaces.  Another take on the namespaces is to use Folders in your project and put the classes in the Folders with the Folder participating in the class name.

Comment: I know of no way to allow public access from referencing projects but disallow internal access from same-project namespaces. Ofcourse you can manually inspect usage with 'find all references' on the class (be sure to start this on the class definition, not on the constructor, otherwise you find instantiation points instead of usage)